# ImportError: cannot import name amount_to_text_sandv

Tags: numpy, python-2.7, importerror, odoo-9, erp

Below is the traceback error. The error arises while installing the odoo9 requirements. Please help me to fix the error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
execute(self.server.app)
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/odoo9/openerp/service/server.py", line 247, in app
return self.app(e, s)
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/odoo9/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application
return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/odoo9/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied
result = handler(environ, start_response)
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/odoo9/openerp/http.py", line 1515, in **call**
return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/odoo9/openerp/http.py", line 1489, in **call**
return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 588, in **call**
return self.app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/odoo9/openerp/http.py", line 1671, in dispatch
ir_http = request.registry['ir.http']
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/odoo9/openerp/http.py", line 376, in registry
return openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(self.db) if self.db else None
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/odoo9/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 355, in get
update_module)
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/odoo9/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 386, in new
openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/odoo9/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 374, in load_modules
force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/odoo9/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 271, in load_marked_modules
perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/odoo9/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 138, in load_module_graph
load_openerp_module(package.name)
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/odoo9/openerp/modules/module.py", line 331, in load_openerp_module
**import**('openerp.addons.' + module_name)
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/odoo9/openerp/modules/module.py", line 61, in load_module
mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/physio-tattva/addons/receipt_voucher_report/**init**.py", line 22, in 
import account_payment
File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/physio-tattva/addons/receipt_voucher_report/account_payment.py", line 32, in 
from openerp.tools import
ImportError: cannot import name amount_to_text_sandv

Answer (score 0):

You should review that module `receipt_voucher_report` because it's the one with the issue. Should be importing `amount_to_text` instead of `amount_to_text_sandv`

File "/home/p7assest/physio_tatva/physio-tattva/addons/receipt_voucher_report/account_payment.py", line 32

There is where the issue it's located